# NodeJS: Writing a response buffer directly to a function argument

Tags: javascript, node.js, buffer, response, bluebird

I have `For of` loop which iterates an array of URL strings, and makes a request using Bluebird's `request-promise` library. I am then using an image-differentiation  library called `resemble.js` to compare a locally saved .JPG to the response .JPG I'm receiving.

So as a test this WORKS (where the first 2 arguments are the same image, read in differently):

```
const compare = require("resemblejs").compare;
const fs = require('mz/fs');

 compare("./r7TielSh4cg.jpg", await fs.readFile("./r7TielSh4cg.jpg"), options, function(err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log("An error!");
                } else {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
```

Now I want that second parameter of compare (which is a buffer according to docs) to be the result of my HTTP request.

Kind like so:

```
const compare = require("resemblejs").compare;
const fs = require('mz/fs');
const rp = require('request-promise');

for (url of await productImageURLarr) {
            //"url" end in .jpg

            let requestJPG = rp('https:' + url).then(data => {
                 ---> Get data buffer into compare() 2nd arg <---   
            });

            const options = {
                returnEarlyThreshold: 5
            };

            // The parameters can be Node Buffers (according to the docs)

            compare("./r7TielSh4cg.jpg", await requestJPG, options, function(err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log("An error!");
                } else {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I have been working on this for a while.

Comment: is there an error with your code? what is the question. You say you want the second argument to be the result of the http request. As long as the second code you posted is being executed inside an `async` function, it should be doing exactly that.

Comment: It's all wrapped in a giant self invoking async function. The only error is when I try to pass an argument to compare that isn't a filepath, or fs.readfile. And I would prefer not to save the response to filesystem, then read it back out again. I want to pipe it or whatever directly into the argument.

Comment: `The only error is` I don't care WHEN you get the error ... what IS the error

Comment: the error is ```FATAL ERROR: v8::ToLocalChecked Empty MaybeLocal. 1: 00007FF74A57814F napi_wrap+121231
 2: 00007FF74A5216F6 uv_loop_fork+44550
 3: 00007FF74A522596 uv_loop_fork+48294
 4: 00007FF74A863A05 v8::V8::ToLocalEmpty+53
 5: 00007FF8D480536E Canvas::stride+255926
 6: 00007FF8D47D64F7 Canvas::stride+63807
 7: 00007FF74AB0A049 v8::internal::OFStreamBase::xsputn+5065
 8: 00007FF74AB09588 v8::internal::OFStreamBase::xsputn+2312
```

Comment: and ... which line of your code is responsible for that

Comment: productImageURLarr looks like ['//www.shop.com/assets/blah.jpg', ... ] with 120 urls where only the .jpg name changes. The error line "console.log(An error)" if i pass err into it obviously

Comment: why are you awaiting an Array?

Comment: The array is satisfied by a page.evaluate. This is essentially a web scraping tool. It is an async operation in the library puppeteer. The URL is definitely not the issue

Comment: `The error line "console.log(An error)" if i pass err into it obviously` - huh? so that error is `err` in `if (err) {`?

Comment: yes thats the one.

Comment: I don't think my request library is returning a buffer for some reason

Comment: When i console log the response with ```rp(https + url).then(data  => console.log(data)``` I get a bunch of diamonds with question marks (unicode?) which continually load

Comment: what code is in `---> Get data buffer into compare() 2nd arg <---`

Comment: don't console.log binary data :p

Comment: ```let comp = rp('https:'+url).then(data => console.log(data))``` returns a bunch of these ����

Comment: ahhh, ok ... try removing the .then altogether

Comment: the issue is that `console.log(data)` returns `undefined` ... which is now the result of the promise ... so you're passing `undefined` as the second argument - if you'd shown the ACTUAL code in the question rather than putting `---> Get data buffer into compare() 2nd arg <---` the problem would've been obvious at a glance :p

Comment: so if I do ``` rp(https + url).pipe(await writeFile(fs.createWriteStream('image4.jpg'))  ```it sort of works. But since its over 100 requests happening rapidly - I get an error about overloading event listeners.

Comment: have you removed the `.then` from `let requestJPG = rp('https:' + url)` which is causing the promise to resolve to `undefined` yet?

Comment: yes I have thank you for pointing that out

Comment: did that fix the problem?

Comment: sorry let me rephrase that, one second

Comment: No it gives me the exact same error, the weird v8 message

Comment: perhaps rp isn't giving you a Buffer ... try `let requestJPG = Buffer.from(await rp('https:' + url), 'binary');` ... now remove the await in the `compare` call, since you've awaited already

Comment: I tried that.... I still get an error ```An error! Error: Unsupported image type``` but I do feel like it's ALOT closer

Comment: let me add binary

Comment: without binary it error'd slowly, with binary it errored quickly but I think it's close -- it should execute each of these in less than half of a second

Comment: you still getting `An error! Error: Unsupported image type`?

Comment: yes, but when I console log the buffer I get ```<Buffer fd fd fd fd 00 10 4a 46 49 46 00 01 01 00 00 01 00 01```

Comment: `4a 46 49 46` - that's JFIF so, on the face of it, looks like a jpeg

Comment: The response headers say content-type "image/jpeg" but the url ends with .jpg

Comment: @JaromandaX I just wrote the JPG to file, and waited for the ```on('close', ...``` event of ```createWriteStream``` to fire -  then used ```compare()``` to read it back out. Wasn't nearly the performance hit I expected. Thank you greatly for the help.